# Call ICommand outside item source

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an ICommand in my PageViewModel and want it to be call in my CheckedChanged of RadioButton. However, this RadioButton is inside:

```
<views:RoundedPage>
<Carousel ItemSource="...">
    <DataTemplate DataType="...">
       <CollectionView ItemSource="...">
         <DataTemplate DataType="...">
           <RadioButton CheckedChanged="" />
         </DataTemplate>
       </CollectionView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Carousel>
</views:RoundedPage>
```

So how am I gonna call this command outside those sources.

Thank you

Comment: Create an event (MyValueChangedEvent ) on your DataContext (ViewModel\Model) bound to the control containing your radioButton. Event shall trigger on Value change of the property bound to your RadioButton. Your PageViewModel shall be subscribed to this event. On RadioButton value changed event will Bubble up to your PageViewModel and there you can Excute your command like CommanName.Execute(bubbled_parameters).

Comment: Hi @A.Dzebo - So in my PageViewModel I have this command

public void CheckValueChanged(object sender, CheckChangedEventArgs args)
{ .... }

And I put in CheckedChanged="CheckValueChanged", but the event is not executing.

Comment: Please visit these links to gather some fundamental knowledge on using Commands and events with Xamarin.Forms:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

At first, I don't recommend you to deal with the UI event in your view model. The view model is used to resolve the logic behavior behand the view.

So you can set the CheckedChanged event by the following method:

1.create a void method in the page.cs, such as

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         //do something
    }
```

2.binding in the xaml

```
  <RadioButton CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"/>
```

If you still want to deal with the event in the viewmodel, you need to use the behavior to covert the event to a command.

There is a simple in the official document and you can check it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/behaviors-eventtocommandbehavior/